# Task doesn't seem to start

Tags: c#, android, android-asynctask, task

Why doesn't this code start the task? I am always getting waiting for activation.
Here I'm doing a simple task which tries to read from clipboard and returns me when the clipboard is accessible. When I run the line, I can see that the task status is waiting for completion.Why is this happening?

```
TaskScheduler scheduler = TaskScheduler.Default;

var fetchTask =
    new Task<Boolean>(() =>
    {
        while (1 == 1)
        {
            try
            {
                IDataObject obj = Clipboard.GetDataObject();
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
            }
        }
    })
    .ContinueWith<Boolean>(
        x =>
        {
         Console.WriteLine("Task completed");
         return true;
        },
    CancellationToken.None,
    TaskContinuationOptions.None, scheduler);
```

Comment: Why don't you guys grab some points?

Comment: cant use start with continue  with.. error on  my machine here

Answer (score 2):

Because... You didn't start it?

```
fetchTask.Start();
```

(CW to respect the two existing comments to this effect)

Answer (score 0):

the tasak is never being started.

```
fetchTask.Start();
```

Comment: WEll i keep getting an error when i use this saying.. start cannot be used when theres a continue with ....

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but try using TaskFactory if `fetchTask.Start()` doesn't work

```
    TaskScheduler scheduler = TaskScheduler.Default;
        var fetchTask = Task<Boolean>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            while (1 == 1)
            {
                try
                {
                    IDataObject obj = Clipboard.GetDataObject();
                    return true;
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                }
            }
        })
        .ContinueWith<Boolean>(
            x =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Task completed");
                return true;
            },
        CancellationToken.None,
        TaskContinuationOptions.None, scheduler);
```